# What are soft skills?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know soft-skills are interpersonal skills, but is there a contorted definition of the word so that includes technical skills?

Let say you are interviewing for the position of a mechanic and you clear a technical interview round and the next round you are told that it is soft skills.. But they ask you about how to operate a fork lift. As a mechanic you might not require to use a fork lift every day, but it is an auxiliary skill. Soft skills also tend to be in the auxiliary skills domain.

Would soft-skills include lesser used technical skills that are auxiliary to the job?

Comment: A hard skill there would be operating the forklift, a soft skill would be knowing how to interact well with fellow workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Soft skills* generally mean skills in dealing with people, things like customer service and communication, and employers can extend this to mean things like being presentable, polite, hygenic, etc.

> Would soft-skills include lesser used technical skills that are auxiliary to the job?

No - anything technical is not a soft skill - though *communicating* or *presenting* about technical topics would be.

You might be thinking that something like "basic computer knowledge" is a soft skill - no, that's a "basic skill."

*Soft skill* is not strictly synonymous with *auxilliary skill* in the manner you're using it, and it's possible a company, etc. may need soft skills to the point where they do not consider it an auxillary skill - e.g. soft skills will be *primary* for a technical salesperson.

It's possible you may encounter someone who doesn't value "soft skills" and therefore uses the term to lump low-level or menial things together, including non-personal skills.  They're using the term incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

On this site we can tell you what people usually mean when they use the term "soft skills". However, we cannot guarantee that a particular interviewer will not include some technical questions during a soft skills interview.

There could be many reasons for this happening.e.g.

- it may be that the interviewer failed to ask some questions during the earlier technical interview, so they included them in the later soft skills interview,
- it may be (as @LawrenceC) suggests) that the interviewer does not place a high value on soft skills, particularly for a technical position,
- it may be that, after the technical interview was finished, it was realised that it would be useful if the new recruit knew how to drive a fork lift.

Anyway, to answer your question:

> Would soft-skills include lesser used technical skills that are auxiliary to the job?

No. Technical skills and soft skills are completely different. However, when you are being interviewed for a job, you often have to expect the unexpected.